# Parse XML in Python from URL

Tags: python, xml

Please help with parse XML from URL.
I'm use 'xml.etree.ElementTree' module.
My XML doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<systeminfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <machines>
        <machine name="server1">
            <applicationserver worker="server1:8173" status="Active"/>
            <vizqlserver worker="server1:8349" status="Active"/>
            <dataserver worker="server1:8723" status="Active"/>
        </machine>
        <machine name="server2">
            <applicationserver worker="server2:8173" status="Active"/>
            <vizqlserver worker="server2:8349" status="Active"/>
            <dataserver worker="server2:8723" status="Active"/>
        </machine>
    </machines>
    <service status="Active"/>
</systeminfo>
```

I need in otput for server1 or server2:

```
 applicationserver - Active
 vizqlserver - Active
 dataserver - Active
```

My code:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree

req = requests.get("http://server/admin/systeminfo.xml")
systeminfo = ET.fromstring(req.content)
```

And then I don't know what to write. I read the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html, tried different designs and I can't do it. Machine name will be put in my code. A need in cycle for specifed machine name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you want:

```
for info in systeminfo.findall(".//machine[@name='server1']")[0]:
    print(info.tag + ": " + info.attrib['status'])
```